# Perform calculations on dataframe columns without creating new columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I am working on evaluating the quality of database records. I have a csv that in binary form tells me whether or not a particular field for each record is missing. My goal is to create a score by attributing different weights for the fields and then calculate a final score 1 - 100. Below is a visual representation of what I am working with. Top two rows are weights and the 3 row on down is what is in my df.

[image]

I was able to do the calculations by matching 1's and 0's to the weights using numpy.where(), writting the results into separate columns and calculating the score using the new columns. I was wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this. My code is below (I shortened the redundant parts to save some space)

```
df = pd.read_csv(path, names=names, usecols=usecols, header=None)

# Main Scoring Weights
contact_info_weight = 0.5
relations_weight = 0.25
demos_weight = 0.25

# Scoring Sub Rations - contact_info
org_address_rate = 30
org_city_rate = 30
.......other.....

# Scoring Sub Rations - relations
related_ind_rate = 40
related_org_rate = 20
related_pc_rate = 50

# Scoring Sub Rations - demos
org_type_rate = 40
market_segment_rate = 30
process_rate = 30

# Create new columns with score values
df['Org Address Line 1 Score'] = np.where(df['Org Address Line 1'] == 1, org_address_rate, 0)
df['Org City Score'] = np.where(df['Org City'] == 1, org_city_rate, 0)
.......other.....

# Calculate total sub scores
df['Contact Info Score'] = df['Org Address Line 1 Score'] + df['Org City Score'] + df['Org State Score'] + \
                     df['Org Postal Code Score'] + df['Org Country Score'] + df['Org Phone Score']

df['Demos Score'] = df['Org Type Score'] + df['Market Segment Score'] + df['Process Score']

df['Relations Score'] = df['Ind ID Score'] + df['Market Segment Score'] + df['Process Score']

# Calculate final score
df['Completeness Score'] = (df['Contact Info Score'] * contact_info_weight) + (df['Demos Score'] * demos_weight) + \
                           (df['Relations Score'] * relations_weight)
```

Comment: It seems to me this question is more suited to be asked in the  [Code Review Forum](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).  Code Review is a question and answer site for peer programmer code reviews. Please read the relevant guidance related to how to properly ask questions on this site before posting your question.